# Where to start thread in service?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, service

As per android documentation long running task should be performed using service and service should be in separate thread. I'm having following question?
Note: I'm using normal service not intent service.
1 By default service runs in main thread, where I need to create thread for executing my long running task onCreate, onStartCommand?
2 In case of bound service where I need to create thread for executing my long running task onCreate, onBind?

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
public class NetworkService extends Service {

    private HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyLocalBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("LocalServiceThread");
        mHandlerThread.start();

        mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());
    }

    public void postRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        mHandler.post(runnable);
    }

    public class MyLocalBinder extends Binder {
        public NetworkService getService() {
            return NetworkService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }
}
```